# Flutter: Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I get this error when i run `flutter build ios` on my MAC machine terminal.

Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found
/Users/stackoverflow/Documents/flow-app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8

I also run try to build from my excode but i still got the same error

```
#if __has_include(<camera_avfoundation/CameraPlugin.h>)
#import <camera_avfoundation/CameraPlugin.h>
#else
@import camera_avfoundation;
#endif
```

Please i need help.

I have regenerated the pod file and installed again but it does not work.

Comment: @Cyrill I have posted the solution below

Comment: run `pod install` in ios directory.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

1. Backup the current native folders(renaming./android and ./iOS)
2. Close Xcode
3. Go to the root folder and run flutter create . (this will generate the native folders)
4. Now your new profile contains all you need.
5. Open Podfile and uncomment platform:ios,'11'. set it to 12
6. Open the .workspace of the ./iOS
7. Set the signing & capabilities
8. Set deployment version
9. Run flutter build iOS
10. Then finally run flutter build ipa

Answer (score 0):

be sure that your Podfile contains the line to install all pods:

> `flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))`

[image: podfile contents]