# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-camera

I have a flutter code with the following dependencies in `pubspec.yml`:

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  bloc: ^8.1.2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  video_player: ^2.7.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  camera: ^0.10.5+5
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  dio: ^5.3.3
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.3+1
  pinput: ^3.0.1
  bottom_picker: ^2.3.2
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
```

Getting the following error:

> Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found
> /Users/~/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator.
> Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

The flutter run fails.

Tried the solution given in

[Flutter: Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595364/flutter-parse-issue-xcode-module-camera-avfoundation-not-found)

and

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138928

I have no solution yet. Please do help me with this.

Comment: run `pod install` in ios directory .